# Вызов функции после последнего клика

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элемент(кнопка), по которому кликают много раз, но функцию нужно вызвать один раз. Пробовал через setTimeout, не получилось(Наверное плохо пробовал).

Comment: А какие гарантии, что вот именно этот клик последний и после него уже не будут кликать? Можно чистить листенер, хоть после первого клика, можно также устанавливать состояние в скрипте, означающее, была ли хоть раз нажата кнопка.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно то что называется `debounce`. Можете глянуть реализации в underscope или lodash.

Comment: Ставите таймаут, если за это время кликнули опять на кнопку - сбрасываете таймер, если не кликнули таймер дойдет до конца и вызвется ваша функция.

Comment: _Пробовал через setTimeout, не получилось_ стоит показать как именно пробовал и почему решил что не получилось

Answer (score 3):

Думаю вы имели в виду что то такое:

```js
var timeout = 3000;
var lastCall = null;

function action() {
    if((Date.now() - lastCall) >= timeout) {
          alert('Action!');
      }

 }

function actionWait() {
  lastCall = new Date();
  setTimeout(action, timeout)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="actionWait()">button</button>
```

Время ожидания задается переменной *timeout*